# sed command does not work for certain characters in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I am trying to replace 300th character and add a positive sign with decimal point accordingly. Sed command works fine perfectly for all characters except for B, F and {.

Please find the input data below:

result_PHDPTRAR2.txt

```
H009704COV2009084    PHD0000001H009700204COV2009084    PROD2015122016010418371304COVH009704COV2009084    PTR0000001H0097002C00000000140000000043610000003408092A0000000068061C0000000000000{0000002939340H0000000537585H0000003476926F0000001218378G0000000040292E0000000016497{0000000000827E0000001880498A9000000320436J000000004391000000001606000000000030000000000128000000000006000000004227000000000000000000000000            00000140              0000000000000{0000000000773B0000000000000{000000000000
```

Here 300th character is **A**. If we use following  sed command , it works correctly for the above requirement:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\{1,255\}\)\(.\{1,34\}\)\(.\{1,9\}\)\(.*\)A/\1\2+\3.\4^/' <<< cat result_PHDPTRAR2.txt
```

It will replace A with ^ and get the following result.

```
H009704COV2009084    PHD0000001H009700204COV2009084    PROD2015122016010418371304COVH009704COV2009084    PTR0000001H0097002C00000000140000000043610000003408092A0000000068061C0000000000000{0000002939340H0000000537585H0000003476926F0000001218378G0000000040292E0000000016497{0000000000827E000+000188049.8^9000000320436J000000004391000000001606000000000030000000000128000000000006000000004227000000000000000000000000            00000140              0000000000000{0000000000773B0000000000000{000000000000
```

But the same commend does not work if we replace 300th character with B, F or {.

if i change 300th character of input(result_PHDPTRAR2.txt) with B and then if i use sed

```
sed -e 's/\(.\{1,255\}\)\(.\{1,34\}\)\(.\{1,9\}\)\(.*\)B/\1\2+\3.\4^/' <<< cat result_PHDPTRAR2.txt
```

i get following result :

```
H009704COV2009084    PHD0000001H009700204COV2009084    PROD2015122016010418371304COVH009704COV2009084    PTR0000001H0097002C00000000140000000043610000003408092A0000000068061C0000000000000{0000002939340H0000000537585H0000003476926F0000001218378G0000000040292E0000000016497{0000000000827E000+000188049.8B9000000320436J000000004391000000001606000000000030000000000128000000000006000000004227000000000000000000000000            00000140              0000000000000{0000000000773^0000000000000{000000000000
```

You can find `+` and decimal point are added correctly in **"+000188049.8B"** but B remains same . Here B should be replaced with **`^`**

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please post the expected output and rephrase the question to make it clear

Comment: I have added expected result now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first 'B' character in the input comes later than the 4..300 character. I.e. the input text doesn't match your expectations.

So, what now?

Update

Based on the comment, the problem is that there's more than 1 B in the text after the 300th character. The .* will go to that point. This is how to fix it:

```
 sed -e 's/\(.\{1,255\}\)\(.\{1,34\}\)\(.\{1,9\}\)\([^B]*\)B/\1\2+\3.\4^/'
```

Watch out for the negated character class: `\([^B]*\)B` - that will go up to the 1st B. Unfortunately, sed doesn't have non-greedy quantifiers. That would make it even more easy: `\(.*?\)B`.

Comment: Before using sed command we need to change 300th character as B in result_PHDPTRAR2.txt

Comment: Aw, I see. You need a non-greedy matcher for \4. Updating the answer.

Comment: can we use the same format if we use perl command instead of sed? I need to think a different option since processing time takes more for sed when input file is huge (around 80000 records)

Comment: I have tried to used the command as perl -pe 's/\(.\{1,255\}\)\(.\{1,34\}\)\(.\{1,9\}\)\([^B]*\)B/\1\2+\3.\4^/' . But it did not give the correct answer. Can we use perl instead of sed here?

Comment: Try to use the backreferences as `$1`, `$2` instead of `\1` and `\2`. Definitely we can use perl - but you need to port the regex carefully.